# Unable to select all image elements

Tags: javascript

I'm using an intersection observer to implement lazy loading on my images. If I only select one image with the querySelector, then it works. But for some reason I can't get querySelectorAll to work. I also tried getElementsByClassName and this is still not working. Any solutions??

```
html:
      <section class="section" id="section--2">
          <div class="photo__container--two">
            <img
              data-src="portrait/4-vertical.JPG"
              alt=""
              class="fade-in img-vertical-lazy"
            />
            <img
              data-src="portrait/5-vertical.JPG"
              alt=""
              class="fade-in img-vertical-lazy"
            />
            <img
              data-src="portrait/6-vertical.JPG"
              alt=""
              class="fade-in img-vertical-lazy"
            />
          </div>
        </section>
    
    JavaScript:
    const lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll('.img-vertical-lazy');
    
 
    
    const lazyLoading = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;
                entry.target.src = entry.target.getAttribute('data-src');
                lazyLoading.unobserve(entry.target)
        });
    });
    
    lazyLoading.observe(lazyImages);
```

Comment: `lazyImages` isn't a node with the `getAttribute` method, it's a NodeList. I imagine you'll have to add each image individually to the observer

Answer (score 2):

According to the [InstersectionObserver docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/observe), the `observe` function receives a single node, not an array of nodes

You should rewrite the last line to this

```js
lazyImages.forEach(image => lazyLoading.observe(image))
```